# Visual Studio 2022 - Configuring custom project build with version control for easily configuring output application

Tags: git, build, visual-studio-2022, project-configuration

I'm facing a problem, where I want to easily switch between how I want to build a project. The entire project is a single .sln with many .csproj files. I want to change output directory and some additional settings with as few steps as possible. I am using version control.

Lets say my project is:

- MainSolution.sln

  - Project1.csproj

    - Settings1.settings
  - Project2.csproj

    - Settings2.settings
  - Project3.csproj

    - Settings3.settings

Project for customer1 should be built in folder /CustomerAlpha. A value in Settings1 should be set to True
Project for customer2 should be built in folder /CustomerBeta. A value in Settings1 should be set to False
Project for customer3 should be built in folder /CustomerGamma. Project3 is not needed and should not be included

I know this can be achieved by having different branches, but I don't want to constantly worry about cherry-picking commits, rebasing or merging... Which is basically what I do now.

I am using Directory.Build.props file to set output directories depending on customer so that I can use the output directory as my debug location (for relative paths within my code).

I know about Project configurations, but currently I only have Debug/Release for conditional compilation. Besides, I have read somewhere that adding build configurations is VS specific and it would not be stored on git and shared between developers?

I heard about making custom controls for visual studio toolbar, but I haven't gotten around to test
this out.. I am assuming this is also VS specific thing and as that and would again introduce problems for multiple developers.

This is as far as I have gotten by searching online, but I ran out of ideas for what to search for...

What would be the best way to achieve this? And how could I make sure that the solution would work regardless of which PC the solution is built on or by which developer?

Thanks for any replies!

(EDIT: fixed formatting)

Comment: "I know about Project configurations, but currently I only have Debug/Release for conditional compilation. Besides, I have read somewhere that adding build configurations is VS specific and it would not be stored on git and shared between developers?" Try this first. (Perhaps a new configuration per customer, or however makes sense.) I believe those changes are stored in project and solution files, which would be tracked and shared by everyone.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. You are right, they are saved. I tried setting it up for only one customer, but I allready stumbled on some issues...
With only one customer I have to make CustomerDebug and CustomerRelease Configurations. This means I have to change every #if Preprocessor directive and keep changing them with every customer. The only reasons this bothers me is because we have like 50 projects...
Also, I cannot find a way to effect the Settings.settings file we use for configuring app settings. I tried SlowCheetah but so far no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further testing I have found a solution that fits me best.

I am relying on Directory.build.props and Configuration manager (Like TTT suggested). This way, I only have to define the Configuration for the main project within the solution and not for every single project.

After creating a new Build Configuration (DebugCustomer1), I define a new macro in Directory.build.props:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration) == DebugCustomer1">
    <ProjectCustomer>Customer1</ProjectCustomer>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In the same file, I have defined settings for each customer:

```
<!-- Settings for Customer1 project -->
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(ProjectCustomer) == Customer1">
    <ProjectTitle>abcdef</ProjectTitle>
    <ClientIP>192.168.1.10</ClientIP>
    <OfflineMode>True</OfflineMode>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Settings for Customer2 project -->
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(ProjectCustomer) == Customer2">
    <ProjectTitle>abcdefghij</ProjectTitle>
    <ClientIP>192.1.1.10</ClientIP>
    <OfflineMode>False</OfflineMode>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I can then pass the macro to any project where I want to use preprocessor directives to control my build by editing the .csproj file like:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
  <DefineConstants>WINDOWS;$(ProjectCustomer)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

End then I can simply use the directive as (example: I want to have different database seed based on customer):

```
#if Customer1
  <code>
#endif
```

Then for the various Settings.settings and app.config files throughout the entire solution I use PostBuild events to replace strings in output files.
For example, in Settings.settings I have a setting named ClientIPAddress with value of ClientIP. In PostBuild event I replace the ClientIP string in the generated file with the value of $(ClientIP) defined in the Directory.build.props.

**UPDATE:**
Using MSBuild I can build the project from the command line and also change any property defined in the Directory.Build.props:

msbuild .csproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:ProjectCustomer=Customer1